# how to generate a plot of planar Cantor set in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am wondering if anyone can help me to plot the [Cantor dust](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Cantor_dust.png/600px-Cantor_dust.png) on the plane in Mathematica. This is linked to the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

I actually wanted to have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a naive and probably not very optimized way of reproducing the graphics for the [ternary Cantor set construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_of_the_ternary_set):

```
cantorRule = Line[{{a_, n_}, {b_, n_}}] :> 
  With[{d = b - a, np = n - .1}, 
       {Line[{{a, np}, {a + d/3, np}}], Line[{{b - d/3, np}, {b, np}}]}]

Graphics[{CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.05], 
  Flatten@NestList[#/.cantorRule&, Line[{{0., 0}, {1., 0}}], 6]}]
```

[image: Ternary Cantor set]

To make [Cantor dust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Cantor_dust) using the same replacement rules, we take the result at a particular level, e.g. 4:

```
dust4=Flatten@Nest[#/.cantorRule&,Line[{{0.,0},{1.,0}}],4]/.Line[{{a_,_},{b_,_}}]:>{a,b}
```

and take tuples of it

```
dust4 = Transpose /@ Tuples[dust4, 2];
```

Then we just plot the rectangles

```
Graphics[Rectangle @@@ dust4]
```

[image]

---

### Edit: Cantor dust + squares

Changed specs -> New, but similar, solution (still not optimized).
Set n to be a positive integer and choice any subset of 1,...,n then

```
n = 3; choice = {1, 3};
CanDChoice = c:CanD[__]/;Length[c]===n :> CanD[c[[choice]]];
splitRange = {a_, b_} :> With[{d = (b - a + 0.)/n}, 
                              CanD@@NestList[# + d &, {a, a + d}, n - 1]];

cantLevToRect[lev_]:=Rectangle@@@(Transpose/@Tuples[{lev}/.CanD->Sequence,2])

dust = NestList[# /. CanDChoice /. splitRange &, {0, 1}, 4] // Rest;

Graphics[{FaceForm[LightGray], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Table[cantLevToRect[lev], {lev, Most@dust}], 
  FaceForm[Black], cantLevToRect[Last@dust /. CanDChoice]}]
```

[image: more dust]

Here's the graphics for

```
n = 7; choice = {1, 2, 4, 6, 7};
dust = NestList[# /. CanDChoice /. splitRange &, {0, 1}, 2] // Rest;
```

and everything else the same:

[image]

Comment: +1 and thank you. I actually wanted to have a plot as the one I attached here. Could you please help with that? It seems more difficult to get a plot like that.

Comment: thanks a lot. I need some explanation here. First of all, I think `np = n - .1` should be `np = n - 1`, shouldn't it? Just puzzled at why the code still produced the correct results? Also how about this line `cantorRule = {CanD[x_,y_,z_]:>(CanD[x,z]/.cantorRule),
              {a_,b_}:>With[{d=(b-a)/3.},CanD@@NestList[#+d&,{a,a+d},2]]};`? I cannot fully understand...

Comment: @QiangLi: The `np=n-.1` was just to get the y-axis spacing right in the first image. Those terms are thrown away in the 2nd image - and a different rule is used to generate the 3rd image.

Comment: @QiangLi: As for the final `cantorRule`, it does two things. The 2nd term takes a pair of x-coordinates and returns a sequence that divides it into 3 equal parts. These are used for drawing the empty squares. The 1st rule then takes these three parts and throws away the middle term - this is what stops the whole thing being filled evenly with squares. Note that in the `Graphics` command I have to manually throw away the middle term when drawing the final, filled squares.

Comment: @QiangLi: I've modified my code to make it clearer and more flexible.

Comment: BTW: The same rules & NestList can be used to generate an animation. E.g. the [{1,3,5} animation](http://i.imgur.com/7Xryn.gif). (When the rectangles get too small, they're not drawn very well...)

Answer (score 3):

Once can use the following approach. Define cantor function:

```
cantorF[r:(0|1)] = r;
cantorF[r_Rational /; 0 < r < 1] := 
 Module[{digs, scale}, {digs, scale} = RealDigits[r, 3];
  If[! FreeQ[digs, 1], 
   digs = Append[TakeWhile[Most[digs]~Join~Last[digs], # != 1 &], 1];];
  FromDigits[{digs, scale}, 2]]
```

Then form the dust by computing differences of `F[n/3^k]-F[(n+1/2)/3^k]`:

```
With[{k = 4}, 
  Outer[Times, #, #] &[
   Table[(cantorF[(n + 1/2)/3^k] - cantorF[(n)/3^k]), {n, 0, 
     3^k - 1}]]] // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like recursive functions, so

```
cantor[size_, n_][pt_] :=
  With[{s = size/3, ct = cantor[size/3, n - 1]},
    {ct[pt], ct[pt + {2 s, 0}], ct[pt + {0, 2 s}], ct[pt + {2 s, 2 s}]}
  ]

cantor[size_, 0][pt_] := Rectangle[pt, pt + {size, size}]

drawCantor[n_] := Graphics[cantor[1, n][{0, 0}]]

drawCantor[5]
```

Explanation: `size` is the edge length of the square the set fits into.  `pt` is the `{x,y}` coordinates of it lower left corner.

Comment: Nice and clean +1! It's also fairly simple to [modify to take arbitrary division patterns](http://pastebin.com/dqGbDtpz) ([animation generated from code](http://i.imgur.com/C6lVO.gif)).